# jQuery animate()'s complete function fires before completion

Tags: jquery

After scrolling the page to a certain element I need to add a class to that element. Problem is, the wrong element gets the class because the complete function fires before completion of the scrolling animation. I know because if I wrap the complete function in a `setTimeout()` it works.

Why would the complete function fire before completion? Is it a known issue? What's the most reliable way to solve this problem?

My code:

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: current_element_position + 'px'
}, 'fast', function(){
  current_element.addClass('current_element');
});
```

Comment: You wrote fast argument for animate function. It has three options to use here: fast, medium and slow. So each has certain time to complete the effect. But JavaScript is asynchronous so it doesn't wait for one action to complete to start the next. If one action takes more time than execution time then the next code will get started execution.

Comment: If what you say is correct then why did they call the complete function "complete" on http://api.jquery.com/animate/? If there are cases where the function fires before actual completion then the term seems pretty misleading to me

Comment: You are correct my friend. But you need to consider this and as you said, set timeout would be helpful to you.

Comment: Could you just be getting confused by the fact that your callback function will happen twice? because that callback should infact be waiting until after the animation is complete. It's likely something else is happening rather than what you think is happening.

Comment: Use the .promise() method to obtain a promise to which you can attach callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the animation effect on 2 elements: `html` and `body`. This means the animation actually runs twice and the complete function also gets called twice.

The reason why this is normally done is because some browsers only support scrolling `html` and others only support scrolling `body`. This selector will target both, which solves that problem, but also causes this double animation call.

The animation that doesn't actually scroll is completed much faster, therefore triggering the complete call before the real animation on the other element is done.

Knowing this you can work around it by setting an extra variable, so your code only gets executed on the last call.

```
var isComplete = false;
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: current_element_position + 'px'
}, 'fast', function() {
  if (isComplete) {
    current_element.addClass('current_element');
    isComplete = false;
  }
  else {
    isComplete = true;
  }
});
```

Or even simpler, use promises.

```
$('html, body')
  .animate({ scrollTop: current_element_position + 'px' }, 'fast')
  .promise()
  .then(function() {
    current_element.addClass('current_element');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your HTML looks like. Nevertheless I hope I got your intention and tried another approach doing without jQuery and animations. It basically checks whether an element's top is within a certain range while the page is scrolled. Maybe it helps ...

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.testdiv');
window.onscroll = function() {
  divs.forEach(function(item) {
    var top = item.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    item.style.background = 'transparent';
    if (top >= 70 && top <= 140) {
      item.style.background = 'red';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.testdiv{
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.testdiv:first-of-type{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
<div class="testdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your intention  is to add Class on scroll to elements which are in view, try below Code.

```js
$(function() {
  /**
 jQuery Custom method to find if element is in View
*/
  $.fn.isInView = function() {
    if (!this.length) return false;
    var rect = this.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );

  };
  /**
 Window Scroll Event:
*/
  $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    /**
        Trigger Custom Event on timeout if Scroll is stopped else clear the timeout
      */
    clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
    $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).trigger('scrollStop')
    }, 50, e));
  });

  /**
         On ScrollStop Loop Through Each Element and check if it is in view, If yes add Class else remove Class
        */
  $(window).on('scrollStop', function(ev) {
    $('div').each(function() {
      var $div = $(this)
      if ($div.isInView()) {
        $div.addClass('color');
      } else {
        $div.removeClass('color');
      }
    });
  }).trigger('scrollStop');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.color {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use window scroll property **
try this it should work. when you scroll to div then class added and when you move again to top then class remove.
you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/surendra786/qnhw5ov7/

```
html --
<p class="new"></div>

 script ---

$('document').ready(function(){
  var current_element=$('.new');
  var current_element_position = $('.new').position().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
  current_element.toggleClass('current_element',
  scroll >= current_element_position
  );

  });
 });
```